# Fast maths: How to rapidly find out the first power $s$ of a number $x$ such that $x^s$ is bigger than a number $m$.

Tags: number-theory

$\newcommand{N}{\mathbb{N}}$Fast maths: How to rapidly find out the first power $s\in\N$ of a number $x$ such that $x^s$ is bigger than a number $m$? I'm assuming $s$, $x$ and $m$ are strictly positive.

I don't even know how to start off

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$x^s>m\iff s\log x>\log m\iff s>\log m/\log x$, unless $x<1$ or something.

Comment: $\newcommand{gangamstyle}{\displaystyle}$Your method is quiet nice, we calculate the ratio $\gangamstyle\frac{\log m}{\log x}$ and we found the first integer that is bigger than that ratio.

Comment: $\newcommand{gangamstyle}{\displaystyle}$For example, find the first power $s$ of $2$ such that $2^s$ is bigger than $1000$, we do $\gangamstyle\frac{\log 1000}{\log 2}=\log_2{1000}\sim 9.9$ so $s$ must be $10$ and indeed, it is the right result since $2^{10}=1024>>512=2^9$.